# Prevent loop from echoing if another same-value array element has been already echoed in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

First of all, sorry for the mis-worded title. I couldn't imagine a better way to put it.

The problem I'm facing is as follows: In a part of my program, the program counts occurences of different `a-zA-Z` letters and then tells how many of each letters can be found in an array. The problem, however, is this:

If I have an array that consists of `A;A;F;A;D` or anything similar, the output will be this:

`A - 3`

`A - 3`

`F - 1`

`A - 3`

`D - 1`

But I am required to make it like this:

`A - 3`

`F - 1`

`D - 1`

I could solve the problem easily, however I can't use an additional array to check what values have been already echoed. I know why it happens, but I don't know a way to solve it without using an additional array.

This is the code snippet (the array simply consists of characters, not worthy of adding it to the snippet):

`n` is the size of array the user is asked to choose at the start of the program (not included in the snippet).

`initburts` is the current array member ID that is being compared against all other values.

`burts` is the counter that is being reset after the loop is done checking a letter and moves onto the next one.

```
do {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        if (array[initburts] == array[i]) {
            burts++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\n" << array[initburts] << " - " << burts;
    initburts++;
    burts = 0;
    if (initburts == n) {
        isDone = true;
    }
}
while (isDone == false);
```

Comment: just sort your array and print all elements on printing check if it was printed if yes just skip to next row

Comment: you could just loop through a sorted version of your array, keep counting occurrences until the letter changes (all in one loop), then output. and output the last one.

Comment: Trying to check if you already printed that value is a very backwards approach and you should only try to print it once

Answer (score 3):

Do your counting first, then loop over your counts printing the results.

```
std::map<decltype(array[0]), std::size_t> counts;
std::for_each(std::begin(array), std::end(array), [&counts](auto& item){ ++counts[item]; });
std::for_each(std::begin(counts), std::end(counts), [](auto& pair) { std::cout << "\n\n" << pair.first << " - " pair.second; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // first check if we printed this character already;
    // this is the case if the same character occurred
    // before the current one:
    bool isNew = true;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        // you find out yourself, do you?
        // do not forget to break the loop
        // in case of having detected an equal value!
    }
    if(isNew)
    {
        // well, now we can count...
        unsigned int count = 1;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
            count += array[j] == array[i];
        // appropriate output...
    }
}
```

That would do the trick and retains the array as is, however is an `O(n²)` algorithm. More efficient (`O(n*log(n))`) is sorting the array in advance, then you can just iterate over the array once. Of course, original array sequence gets lost then:

```
std::sort(array, array + arrayLength);
auto start = array;
for(auto current = array + 1; current != array + arrayLength; ++current)
{
    if(*current != *start)
    {
        auto char = *start;
        auto count = current - start;
        // output char and count appropriately 
    }
}
// now we yet lack the final character:
auto char = *start;
auto count = array + arrayLength - start;
// output char and count appropriately
```

Pointer arithmetic... Quite likely that your teacher gets suspicious if you just copy this code, but it should give you the necessary hints to make up your own variant (use indices instead of pointers...).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;

    vector<int> capCount(26, 0), smallCount(26, 0);

    cout << "Enter the string\n";
    cin >> s;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        char c = s.at(i);

        if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            ++capCount[(int)c - 65];

        if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            ++smallCount[(int)c - 97];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        if(capCount[i] > 0)
            cout << (char) (i + 65) << ": " << capCount[i] << endl;

        if(smallCount[i] > 0)
            cout << (char) (i + 97) << ": " << smallCount[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Note: I have differentiated lower and upper case characters.

Here's is the sample output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JUDx.png)